# Help with a Inno Setup script for C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, inno-setup

I need to create a INNO Setup script that will allow me to have a dialog, where the user can type in a serial number, then I need to save the serial number they entered into the Windows registry.

Also, if they don't enter a serial number, the next button needs to be disabled, so that they cannot proceed with the installation, if they do not enter a serial number.

Any help would be greatly appriceated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stripped down sample of what I use in my scripts.  Also, take a look at the InnoSetup docs for CheckSerial (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_userinfopage.htm).

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{6EAB4CDD-5D03-4EA1-BE97-7102D27CE955}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "User"; ValueData: "{userinfoname}"
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SN"; ValueData: "{userinfoserial}"

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, "&", "&&")}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[Code]
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
var
sTrial : string;
sSerial : string;

begin
sTrial := 'trial';
sSerial := lowercase(Serial);
  if (length(Serial) <> 25)  AND (sTrial <> sSerial) then
    Result := false
  else
    Result := true;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great, but it's not writing the registry settings...Any ideas?

Comment: Does it create any of the keys?

Comment: Only the ones in HKLM, but I need to read them from a C# WinForms application, where the user will not have admin privileges. So I need to store the settings in HKCU. I cannot seem to be able to write any keys to HKCU.

Comment: You should be able to read from HKLM from C# without any problems.  It's only writing that requires admin rights.  Storing serial numbers to HKCU would cause problems when another user tries to run the software because it would not be able to read the registry settings from the original user.

Answer (score 0):

Inno can prompt the user for this information when you set the UserInfoPage=yes directivve.
If you add a CheckSerial event function, it will also ask for the registration details.

See the [UserInfoPage](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_userinfopage.htm) page in the help file for more details.